# ASP Net Core model validation Range attribute is ignored

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, attributes, range

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.3.

In `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddSingleton<ILocationService, LocationService>()
        .AddSingleton(_ => BootStatus.Instantiate())
        .AddScoped<IClock>(_ => new ZonedClock(SystemClock.Instance, DateTimeZone.Utc, CalendarSystem.Iso))
        .AddHostedService<BootService>()
        .AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters()
        .AddApiExplorer()
        .AddAuthorization();

    /* Other code, not relevant here. */
}
```

In my HTTP controller I have a GET:

```
[HttpGet(nameof(Location))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Location(
    LocationQueryParameters queryParams)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
    }

    var response = await locationService.Retrieve(
        queryParams.Category,
        queryParams.ItemsCount);
    return StatusCode(200, response);
}
```

Here's my parameters object:

```
public class LocationQueryParameters
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "category")]
    [BindRequired]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [FromQuery(Name = "itemsCount")]
    [BindRequired]
    [Range(1, 999)]
    public int ItemsCount { get; set; }
}
```

The Range attribute is completely ignored. Similarly, if I attach a StringLength attribute to the string property, it's ignored. I also tried writing a custom ValidationAttribute, but stepping through the code never hits the IsValid method. BindRequired and FromQuery are working fine, so what am I doing wrong that prevents the data annotation style of validation? I'd prefer not to write all my validation manually.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with your code and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.3`, it return expected value `{"itemsCount":["The field ItemsCount must be between 1 and 999."]}` when `https://localhost:44315/location?category=123&itemscount=11111`.

Comment: @TaoZhou I haven't got a demo available, this is part of a much larger project. I'll see if I can reproduce it in a less complex example and update this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `.AddMvcCore()`, which is a bare bones version of `.AddMvc()`. See more information about this here: https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/07/difference-between-addmvc-addmvcore/

The solution is to add `.AddDataAnnotations()`, a service which is normally added by `.AddMvc()`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddSingleton<ILocationService, LocationService>()
        .AddSingleton(_ => BootStatus.Instantiate())
        .AddScoped<IClock>(_ => new ZonedClock(SystemClock.Instance, DateTimeZone.Utc, CalendarSystem.Iso))
        .AddHostedService<BootService>()
        .AddMvcCore()
        .AddDataAnnotations()
        .AddJsonFormatters()
        .AddApiExplorer()
        .AddAuthorization();

    /* Other code, not relevant here. */
}
```